# whereBetween not working with dates as expected

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a query like this:

```
App\Model::where('some', 'condition')->orWhere('some', 'other_condition')->whereBetween('created_at', [request('from'), request('to')])->get();
```

Why the `whereBetween` clause not working here? Instead of returning the records between the provided dates, it returns all the records.

Here are the request params:

```
from: 2018-08-14
to:   2018-08-09
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is doing:

```
select from blah where some=condition or some=other_condition and created_at between date1 AND date2.
```

You can run DB::enableQueryLog(); before the query then print_r(DB::getQueryLog());
 to see the actual query that's being run.

Might want to try

```
App\Model::
  whereBetween('created_at', [request('from'), request('to')])
  ->where(function($query) { 
     $query
     ->where('some', 'condition')
     ->orWhere('some', 'other_condition')
   })->get();
```

I think that'll do

```
select from blah where created_at between date1 AND date2 and (some=condition or some=other_condition).
```

Answer (score 1):

As your query

```
App\Model::where('some', 'condition')->orWhere('some', 'other_condition')->whereBetween('created_at', [request('from'), request('to')])->get();
```

It was like below query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `some` = 'text' OR `some` = 'other_text' AND `created_at` BETWEEN 'from' AND 'to'
```

So from this query it will return all data which was having **some = text or some = other text**

you need to make query like below

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (`some` = 'text' OR `some` = 'other_text') AND `created_at` BETWEEN 'from' AND 'to'
```

So it will check for between date and text

**You should try This**:

```
App\Model::whereRaw('some = condition OR some = other_condition')->whereBetween('created_at', [request('from'), request('to')])->get();
```

Comment: Accepted @AlexandruPetrescu's answer. To appreciate your effort, upvoting yours. Someday, your method might also be helpful. But for the time being I am not going with the `whereRaw` approach.